# Angularjs, unable to run the angular js application

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

My angularjs application is running fine till I made few changes recently. Since then I    am getting the following error (taken from Firebug). I don't know which part of the code is causing this error. So I reverted my changes, even then I am getting the same error.

From this error stack trace, is there any possibility for me to know which part of my angular js code is causing this issue? As my application is big one, I don't know which part of the code I can provide you for your reference without knowing which part of the code has caused this error.

In this error stack trace, I don't find even a single reference to the functions name, objects name, etc that I have created in my angularjs application. All the line references in this show line numbers of Angular.js file only. Can any one direct me, how can I know which part of my angularjs code is causing this error?

```
Error: node is undefined compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:5989:13 compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:5989:13 nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:6573:1 compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:5986:15 compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:5989:13 publicLinkFn@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:5891:30 bootstrap/doBootstrap/</<@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:1384:11 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:12412:16 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:12510:18 bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:1382:9 invoke@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:3869:14 bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:1380:1 bootstrap@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:1394:1 angularInit@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:1307:5 @http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:21459:5 trigger@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:2509:7 createEventHandler/eventHandler/<@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:2780:7 forEach@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:330:11 createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:2779:5
consoleLog/<()angular.js (line 9778)
$ExceptionHandlerProvider/this.$get</<(exception=
TypeError: node is undefined


childLinkFn(scope, node.childNodes, undefined, boundTranscludeFn);

, cause=undefined)angular.js (line 7216)
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply()angular.js (line 12512)
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<(scope=Scope { $id="002", $$childTail=Scope, $$childHead=Scope, more...}, element=Object[html.ng-scope], compile=compile($compileNodes, transcludeFn, maxPriority, ignoreDirective, previousCompileContext), injector=Object { invoke=invoke(), instantiate=instantiate(), get=getService(), more...}, animate=Object { enter=function(), leave=function(), move=function(), more...})angular.js (line 1382)
invoke(fn=function(scope, element, compile, injector, animate), self=undefined, locals=undefined)angular.js (line 3869)
bootstrap/doBootstrap()angular.js (line 1380)
bootstrap(element=Object[html.ng-scope], modules=["ng", ["$provide", function($provide)], "myApp"])angular.js (line 1394)
angularInit(element=Document testDashboard.do, bootstrap=bootstrap(element, modules))angular.js (line 1307)
angular.js()angular.js (line 21459)
trigger()angular.js (line 2509)
createEventHandler/eventHandler/<(fn=trigger())angular.js (line 2780)
forEach(obj=Object { 0=trigger()}, iterator=function(fn), context=undefined)angular.js (line 330)
createEventHandler/eventHandler(event=DOMContentLoaded , type=undefined)angular.js (line 2779)


return logFn.apply(console, args);
```

The following are some of the templates I have used in my controller and compiling them.

```
var template = ' <div class="table-container"> <smart-table  config="globalConfig" columns="columnCollection" rows="rowCollection"></smart-table>   </div> ';


                        angular.element(
                                        document.querySelector('.snap-content'))
                                .append($compile(template)($scope));



var template = ' <div class="col"> '
                        + ' <p class="graphtitle"> NetSpend Over Time </p> <nvd3 id = "chart3" options="netspendovertime_options" data="netspendovertime_data"></nvd3>   </div>';


                    angular
                            .element(
                                    document.querySelector('.snap-content'))
                            .append($compile(template)($scope));
```

Before compiling each template, I remove most of the existing templates DOM elements as shown below. Is there any wrong in this approach?

```
// Remove the previously plotted graphs
                    var charts = angular.element(document.body)
                            .find('nvd3')
                    var cntGraphs = charts.length;

                    if (cntGraphs) {
                        while (cntGraphs > 0) {
                            console.log(charts[cntGraphs - 1].parentNode.remove())
                            charts[cntGraphs - 1].remove();
                            cntGraphs = cntGraphs - 1;
                        }

                    }

                    // Remove the previous Titles
                    var tiltles = angular.element(document.body).find('p')
                    var cntTiltles = tiltles.length;

                    if (cntTiltles) {
                        while (cntTiltles > 0) {
                            tiltles[cntTiltles - 1].remove();
                            cntTiltles = cntTiltles - 1;
                        }

                    }

                    // Remove Welcome Images
                    var images = angular.element(document.body).find('img')
                    var cntImages = images.length;

                    if (cntImages) {
                        while (cntImages > 0) {
                            images[cntImages - 1].remove();
                            cntImages = cntImages - 1;
                        }

                    }

                    // Remove All Smart Tables
                    var smartTlbs = angular.element(document.querySelector('.smart-table'))

                    var cntsmartTlbs = smartTlbs.length;

                    if (cntsmartTlbs) {
                        while (cntsmartTlbs > 0) {
                            smartTlbs[cntsmartTlbs - 1].remove();
                            cntsmartTlbs = cntsmartTlbs - 1;
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Do you have any directives or controllers that are manipulating DOM anywhere other than the link function of the directive?

Comment: Yes Jeff Cross, I am compiling templates in my controller and edited my question with sample templates I have used.

Comment: Jeff Cross,  Other than this Dom manipulation in Controller I have not created any directive to manipulate the DOM. However I have used some official directives, like nvd3, smartTable.table, angular snap, ui.tree, ui.bootstrap. I feel all these directives does Dom manipulations in link function only.

Comment: I remove most of the existing template DOM elements before compiling new template. I have edited my question even with that part of code.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting sufficient amount of time on this, small thought came to check application in chrome. Then in chrome I got the full stack trace, I am not sure why firebug missed this information. The root problem triggered from my $scope.allNeedsMet (some thing related to underscore.js).

**With this experience I suggest developers to try with different browsers for error logs then it can really save lot your time in the issues of this kind.**

```
 ReferenceError: _ is not defined
        at Scope.$scope.allNeedsMet (http://localhost/dashboard2/js/controllers.js:160:22)
        at Object.get (http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:10567:21)
        at Scope.$digest (http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:12243:40)
        at Scope.$apply (http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:12516:24)
        at http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:1382:15
        at Object.invoke (http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:3869:17)
        at doBootstrap (http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:1380:14)
        at bootstrap (http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:1394:12)
        at angularInit (http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:1307:5)
        at http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js:21459:5 angular.js:9778(anonymous function) angular.js:9778(anonymous function) 
angular.js:7216Scope.$digest angular.js:12270Scope.$apply angular.js:12516(anonymous function)
 angular.js:1382invoke angular.js:3869doBootstrap angular.js:1380bootstrap angular.js:1394angularInit 
angular.js:1307(anonymous function) angular.js:21459trigger angular.js:2509(anonymous function) angular.js:2780forEach angular.js:330eventHandler
```